# Mysql events wont start

Tags: mysql, events

I'm running mysql 5.5.6. It was working, then crashed.

I re-installed server, then restored db which has SP and events. My SP show up, but my events dont. The Infomation_schema/events table is blank.

I had this problem before, I ran something from C: prompt I cant remember what I did?

Its not global event_scheduler problem.

The events are in routines table but not in events table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a bug! 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57451